# How to create objects out of each element in array?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, module

I have a module with a new constructor:

```
package myClass;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $arrayreference = shift;
    bless $arrayreference, $class;
    return $arrayreference;
};
```

I want to do something like:

```
foreach $ref (@arrayref)
{
     $array1 = myClass->new($ref);
}
```

`$array1` is being rewritten each time, but I want each element in the array to have a distinct object name (ex. `$array1`, `$array2`, `$array3` etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with a plural data structure (an array), then you need to store the result into a plural container (or multiple scalar containers).  The idomatic way to do this is to use the `map` function:

```
my @object_array = map {myClass->new($_)} @source_array;
```

If you know that `@source_array` contains a fixed number of items, and you want scalars for each object:

```
my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = map {myClass->new($_)} @source_with_3_items;
```

Comment: So my @object_array = map {myClass->new($_)} @source_array; will be an array of my objects?

How would I call a function of a certain object?

Comment: You would access each element by index in the array: `$object_array[2]->some_method(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use some hash or array to contain the objects.

```
foreach $ref (@arrayref)
{
     push @array, myClass->new($ref);
     $hash{$key++} = myClass->new($ref);
}
```

thus you can access them with `$array[42]` or `$hash{42}`.

Answer (score 2):

There is essentially no *name* difference between `$array[1]` and `$array1`. There is a programmatic difference in that `$array[1]` can be "pieced together" and, under modern Perl environments `$array1` can't. Thus I can write `$array[$x]` for any valid `$x` and get an item with a "virtual name" of `$array.$x`.

```
my @objects = map { MyClass->new( $_ ); } @data_array;
```

Thus, if you just want to append a number, you probably just want to collect your objects in an array. However, if you want a more complex naming scheme, one or more levels of hashes is probably a good way to go.

If you had a way to derive the name from the object data once formed, and had a method called `name`, you could do this:

```
my %object_map 
    = map { my $o = MyClass->new( $_ ); ( $o->name => $o ); } @data_array
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you are trying to do it in place?

```
my @objects = (
    { ...args for 1st object... },
    { ...args for 2nd object... },
    ...
);

$_ = Class->new($_) for @objects;
```

However, you should avoid reusing variables like that.

```
my @object_data = (
    { ...args for 1st object... },
    { ...args for 2nd object... },
    ...
);

my @objects = map Class->new($_), @object_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ade YU and Eric Strom, and have +1'd their answers: you should use one of their approaches. But what you ask *is* technically possible, using symbolic references, so for completeness' sake:

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#arrayref)
{
    no strict refs;
    my $varname = 'array' . ($i + 1);
    ${$varname} = myClass->new($arrayref[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Ya. Good answer. Exactly what the asker needs. Hope the asker to know it's not good practice.